# Hibernate storing value with Enum, int or String

Tags: hibernate, enums, store, bigdata

For my entities which one should I use for storing values such as status, type etc...?

I defined my status, types etc...many predefined system data to my system with enums. In a short future I plan to migrate system to big data databases. So, while storing these data what should I do?

- It is out of debate, I cannot use @Convert because it doesnt support by envers.
- It is important future development and system may needs to update enums so I can not use ordinal.
- My predefined enums already exist and I can assign a id for each enum. So, it is require entity needs to be defined as int. (Manage as enum, store as int id.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
public enum Status {
    NORMAL(0), BANNED(1); // modify it

    int code;

    Status(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public static Status fromCode(int code) {
        switch (code) {
            case 0:
                return NORMAL;
            case 1:
                return BANNED;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

Then, let's say you would store Status in object's variable named "status":

```
public Status getStatus() {
    return Status.fromCode(status);
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status.getCode();
}
```

And store status in database as int.